# Do OpenCL vector types use SIMD

Tags: math, vector, floating-point, opencl, simd

I currently have a large array of floats that I process in my OpenCL kernel i am wondering if i divide this array up and use an OpenCL vector type array instead, if it will speed up the process. Basically if i had an array of 4,800 floats i would divide it up into an array of 300 float16 vectors. Would this take advantage of SIMD?

Comment: OpenCL should already take advantage of the SIMD features of the underlying hardware, or it would be quite useless for GPU programming. I'm not sure what it does on the CPU though, although the CPU isn't OpenCL's perfect domain to play its strengths, anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intel actually describes what their OpenCL SDK does: see [Writing Optimal OpenCL™ Code with Intel® OpenCL SDK](http://software.intel.com/file/37171/). You might want to check that out, as an addition to benchmarking. The interesting part starts at chapter 2.3.

To answer your question: yes, it will take advantage of SIMD. But to "maximize utilization of the CPU vector units by using vector data types" you should really read that document.

Answer (score 0):

It might, or it might not. It is dependent on the implementation of OpenCL, and the hardware on which your program executes.

The only way to see if it provides an improvement is to benchmark on the platforms and implementations of interest - for the range of vector sizes (e.g. compare 1 (scalar), 2, 4, 8 and 16).